# How to compose Free Monads

Tags: haskell, free-monad

```hs
data Console a
  = PutStrLn String a
  | GetLine (String -> a)
  deriving (Functor)

type ConsoleM = Free Console

runConsole :: Console (IO a) -> IO a
runConsole cmd =
  case cmd of
    (PutStrLn s next) -> do
      putStrLn s
      next
    (GetLine nextF) -> do
      s <- getLine
      nextF s

runConsoleM :: ConsoleM a -> IO a
runConsoleM = iterM runConsole

consolePutStrLn :: String -> ConsoleM ()
consolePutStrLn str = liftF $ PutStrLn str ()
consoleGetLine :: ConsoleM String
consoleGetLine = liftF $ GetLine id


data File a
  = ReadFile FilePath (String -> a)
  | WriteFile FilePath String a
  deriving (Functor)

type FileM = Free File

runFile :: File (MaybeT IO a) -> MaybeT IO a
runFile cmd = case cmd of
  ReadFile path next -> do
    fileData <- safeReadFile path
    next fileData
  WriteFile path fileData next -> do
    safeWriteFile path fileData
    next

runFileM :: FileM a -> MaybeT IO a
runFileM = iterM runFile

rightToMaybe :: Either a b -> Maybe b
rightToMaybe = either (const Nothing) Just

safeReadFile :: FilePath -> MaybeT IO String
safeReadFile path =
  MaybeT $ rightToMaybe <$> (try $ readFile path :: IO (Either IOException String))

safeWriteFile :: FilePath -> String -> MaybeT IO ()
safeWriteFile path fileData =
  MaybeT $ rightToMaybe <$> (try $ writeFile path fileData :: IO (Either IOException ()))

fileReadFile :: FilePath -> FileM String
fileReadFile path = liftF $ ReadFile path id
fileWriteFile :: FilePath -> String -> FileM ()
fileWriteFile path fileData = liftF $ WriteFile path fileData ()


data Program a = File (File a) | Console (Console a)
  deriving (Functor)
type ProgramM = Free Program

runProgram :: Program (MaybeT IO a) -> MaybeT IO a
runProgram cmd = case cmd of
  File cmd' ->
    runFile cmd'
  Console cmd' ->
    -- ????

runProgramM :: ProgramM a -> MaybeT IO a
runProgramM = iterM runProgram
```

I want to compose two free monads `ConsoleM` and `FileM`. So, I made composed functor `Program`. Then I started to write interpreter functrion `runProgram`, but I cannot define the function. Because `runConsole` and `MaybeT IO a` types are not matched. How can I lift runConsole function `runConsole :: Console (IO a) -> IO a` to have type `Console (MaybeT IO a) -> MaybeT IO a`?

(I want to implement this program with Free monads for practice, not Eff monad.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now you have `cmd'` of type `Console (MaybeT IO a)`, and want to pass it to a function taking `Console (IO a)`. The first thing you can do is to run the `MaybeT` monad inside `Console` and get `Console (IO (Maybe a))`. You can do this by `fmap`ping `runMaybeT`.

Once you got `Console (IO (Maybe a))`, you can pass it to `runConsole` and get `IO (Maybe a)`. Now, you can lift it to `MaybeT IO a` using `MaybeT`.

So it'll be something like this.

```
runProgram :: Program (MaybeT IO a) -> MaybeT IO a
runProgram cmd = case cmd of
  File cmd' ->
    runFile cmd'
  Console cmd' ->
    MaybeT $ runConsole $ fmap runMaybeT cmd'
```